# How to get the first element in a string?

Tags: delphi, string

I'm trying to figure out a way to check a string's first element if it's either a number or not.

```
if not(myString[0] in [0..9]) then //Do something
```

The problem is that I get an error "Element 0 inaccessible - use 'Length' or 'SetLength"

Another way came to my head from my C-like exprieince - convert the first element of the string to char and check the char,but there is no difference in the compile errors.

```
if not(char(myString[0]) in [0..9]) then //Do something
```

How do I accomplish it?

Comment: BTW: the return type of the expression myString[1] already is a Char so doing an explicit cast serves no purpose here

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Strings are 1-based:

```
if not (myString[1] in ['0'..'9']) then // Do something
```

Comment: Just one problem now "incompatible types - string and integer". If I use StrToInt and the string isn't an integer then an exception will be thrown and all that check is useless.Could you suggest a better way? +1 by the way. :)

Comment: Look again at TOndrej's code: There should be single-quotes around the '0'..'9'

Comment: In modern versions of Delphi string is 1-based only for Windows platform, for mobile platforms string is 0-based. It means that suggested code is compatible with Windows platform only.

Comment: Now you must use CharInSet, because Char in [] is deprecated.
if (not CharInSet(myString[1], ['0'..'9']) then

Answer (score 16):

Pascal and Delphi indexes string from 1. This is a legacy from time where zero byte contained length, while next 255 (index 1 to 255) contained actual characters.
Joel Spolsky wrote quite good article on string issues: 
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Comment: The "Spolsky" article talks about implementing Pascal strings in C without any compiler support. The problems are irrelevant for languages that have support for it.

Comment: @Marco van de Voort: I am afraid you completely missed the point of Joel’s article.

Answer (score 8):

Delphi strings use a 1-based index, so just rewrite to

```
if not(myString[1] in ['0'..'9']) then //Do something
```

Also take note of the quotes around the `0..9`, otherwise you would be comparing characters to integers.

Answer (score 6):

We should keep in mind some things:

1. String in Delphi is 0-based for mobile platforms and 1-based for Windows.
2. String in old versions of Delphi is `AnsiString` (1-byte per char) and `WideString` in new versions (2-bytes per char).
3. Delphi supports set of `AnsiChar`, but doesn't support set of `WideChar`.

So if we want to write a code compatible with all versions of Delphi, then it should be something like this:

```
if (myString[Low(myString)]>='0') and (myString[Low(myString)]<='9') then
  // Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

> if not(myString[0] in [0..9]) then //Do something

If you're using Delphi 2009, the TCharacter class in Character.pas has functions like IsDigit to help simplify these kinds of operations.

Once you fix the indexing, of course.  :)

Comment: The cast to Char() isn't necessary, as a string is made up of chars and they can be accessed directly. Also, your comparison would be wrong anyway, as Char('0') is decimal 48 (hex 30), and therefore wouldn't fall between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 1):

With later updates to Delphi mobile code, the bottom string index changed from 0 to 1.  When you compile older programmes, they compile and run correctly using 0 starting index.  Programmes created with the later IDE produce an error.  When you have mixtures, life gets complex!

It would be good to be able to take an older programme and tell the IDE that you want it brought up to date (maybe this would fix other things, like fonts getting scrambled when you answer a phone call!) but it would be good to get things consistent!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to check to see if the first character of string is an integer, and then dispatch:

```
var
  iResult : integer;
begin
  if TryStrToInt( mySTring[1], iResult) then
    begin
      // handle number logic here iResult = number
    end
  else
    begin
      // handle non number logic here
    end;
end;
```

Comment: No, I don't think that's the simplest way at all. John actually had the right idea, but was fumbling around in the dark for the proper syntax.

Comment: True, but if you wanted to act on the value then it required using StrtoInt.  If you use TryStrToInt you not only can check to see if its a number, you then have the number to then use.

Answer (score 0):

I use a utility function to test the entire string:

```
function IsNumeric(const Value: string): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  for i := 1 to Length(Value) do
    if not (Value[i] in ['0'..'9','.','+','-']) then
    begin
      Result := False;
      Break;
    end;
end;
```

The above code is for Delphi versions prior to 2007. In 2007 and 2009, you could change the integer variable i to a character c, and use for c in Value instead.

To test for integers only, remove the '.' from the set of characters to test against.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect. ISO strings and older Pascal's also started at one. It is just a general convention, and afaik the s[0] thing is a result of that being vacant, and cheap to code in the UCSD bytecode interpreter. But that last bit is before my time, so only my guessing.

It results from the Pascal ability to have arbitrary upper and lower bounds, which provides for more typesafety accessing arrays.

Really old Pascal strings (till early eighties) strings were even worse than C ones btw. Multiple conventions were in used, but all were based on static arrays (like early C), but they were typically space padded, so you had scan back from the end till the spaces ended.

(removed the legacy tag, since being 1 based is not legacy. Accessing s[0] as length IS legacy, but that is not what the question is about)

Answer (score 0):

```
Foreach element in strName
  if not element in [0-9] then
     do something 
  else
    element is a digit
end if
```

Don't forget the quote between digits number.